# Spark : onApplicationStart is never gets called

Tags: apache-spark, stream

**MyJavaSparkListener** class

```
package com.streamanalytix.spark.core.pipeline;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.spark.JavaSparkListener;
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerApplicationEnd;
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerApplicationStart;
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded;
import org.apache.spark.scheduler.SparkListenerBlockManagerRemoved;

public class MyJavaSparkListener extends JavaSparkListener {

    /** The Constant LOGGER. */
    private static final Log LOGGER = LogUtil.getLogger(MyJavaSparkListener.class);

    public MyJavaSparkListener() {
        super();
        LOGGER.info("---------------------------------------------- Creating new SaxJavaSparkListener");
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationStart(SparkListenerApplicationStart arg0) {
        LOGGER.info("---------------------------------------------- Spark pipeline is up and running...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEnd(SparkListenerApplicationEnd arg0) {
        LOGGER.info("---------------------------------------------- Spark pipeline going to shutdown...");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBlockManagerAdded(SparkListenerBlockManagerAdded blockManagerAdded) {
        LOGGER.info("---------------------------------------------- onBlockManagerAdded");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBlockManagerRemoved(SparkListenerBlockManagerRemoved blockManagerRemoved) {
        LOGGER.info("---------------------------------------------- onBlockManagerRemoved");
    }
}
```

I am registering this listener with below line

```
context.sparkContext().sc().addSparkListener(new MyJavaSparkListener());
```

I am running Spark application in client mode but I do not see any logs printed for `onApplicationStart` or `onApplicationEnd`. However, `onBlockManagerAdded` is called and logs are printed.
I do not know what is the use of `onApplicationStart` or how to use it as documentation is too limited.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `SparkListenerApplicationStart` has already been sent before you register the listener. To avoid that, you can use the configuration `spark.extraListeners`. Then Spark will register your listener before any events. Here is the instruction about this configuration (http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#application-properties):

> A comma-separated list of classes that implement SparkListener; when initializing SparkContext, instances of these classes will be created and registered with Spark's listener bus. If a class has a single-argument constructor that accepts a SparkConf, that constructor will be called; otherwise, a zero-argument constructor will be called. If no valid constructor can be found, the SparkContext creation will fail with an exception.